# Retrieving TOP Count from Acumatica

Tags: api, acumatica

I noticed that the Top Count of the export functions [for e.g IN401000Export()] only works at the top-most level (when there is more than one level required).

For example we are trying to retrieve the TOP 200 lines from the Bin Location Content. In this case we are looking at retrieving 200 Item/Warehouse/ Bin Location at a time. But instead of retrieving the TOP 200 Item/Warehouse/Bin Location combination, the system attempts to retrieve the TOP 200 Items. Note that the reason behind is to implement some pagination structure in the software.

To illustrate this better, assume below are the data in the database:

```html
Item  Warehouse  Bin  Qty
AA    MAIN       01   25
AA    MAIN       02   20
AA    MAIN       03   2
BB    MAIN       01   10
BB    MAIN       02   5
BB    STORE      S1   10
CC    MAIN       01   50
CC    STORE      S1   10
CC    STORE      S2   10
DD    MAIN       02   23
```

What I wanted to achieve was retrieving TOP 3 of the table so I can create pages of 3 records which should result in:

```html
Page 1
AA    MAIN       01   25
AA    MAIN       02   20
AA    MAIN       03   2
Page 2
BB    MAIN       01   10
BB    MAIN       02   5
BB    STORE      S1   10
Page 3
CC    MAIN       01   50
CC    STORE      S1   10
CC    STORE      S2   10
Page 4
DD    MAIN       02   23
```

However, the system is grabbing the TOP 3 Items instead along with all its trailing content:

```html
Page 1
AA    MAIN       01   25
AA    MAIN       02   20
AA    MAIN       03   2
BB    MAIN       01   10
BB    MAIN       02   5
BB    STORE      S1   10
CC    MAIN       01   50
CC    STORE      S1   10
CC    STORE      S2   10
Page 2
DD    MAIN       02   23
```

Below is the code I am using to retrieve the data, I tried adding EveryWarehouse and EveryLocation from the ServiceCommands but it did not help.
The same issue happens in any other table (Purchase Orders & Lines, Sales Orders & Lines, Warehouse & Bin Locations and so on)
Can you please advise what can be changed in the code to achieve what is required?
Or tell me if this is how we are supposed to retrieve the data?

```
Command[] oCmd = new Command[] {IN401000.Selection.ServiceCommands.EveryInventoryID,
                           IN401000.Selection.ServiceCommands.EveryWarehouse,
                            IN401000.Selection.ServiceCommands.EveryLocation,
                            IN401000.Selection.InventoryID,
                            IN401000.InventorySummary.Warehouse,
                            IN401000.InventorySummary.Location,
                            IN401000.InventorySummary.Available,
                            IN401000.InventorySummary.AvailableForShipment,
                            IN401000.InventorySummary.OnHand,
                            new Field {ObjectName = IN401000.Selection.InventoryID.ObjectName,
                                       FieldName = "LastModifiedDateTime"}
                           };

Filter[] oFilter = new Filter[] {}
String[][] sReturn = oScreen.IN401000Export(oCmd, oFilter, 200, true, false);
```

Comment: This looks like the same question asked a day later.

Answer (score 0):

Come over here guessing why Inquiry windows has broken the Export method. I find the answer in the training guide: As you already know, IN401000 is an Inquiry Window, so you must "fill" the "filter" fields contents with your filter data (remember to committ to the last one)

From "Screen-Based Web Services Training Guide", Example 2.2.2: Retrieving the Quantities of a Stock Item:

```
//Stock item data (FILTER FIELDS)
string inventoryID = "AALEGO500";
string warehouse = "MAIN";
using
(
    //Connect to the web services and log in to Acumatica ERP
    Screen context = WebServiceConnector.InitializeWebService()
)
{
    try
    {
        //Get the schema of the form
        IN401000Content invSummarySchema = context.IN401000GetSchema();
        //Configure the list of commands
        var commands = new Command[]
        {
        //Select the needed stock item
        new Value
        {
            Value = inventoryID,
            LinkedCommand = invSummarySchema.Selection.InventoryID
        },
        new Value
        {
            Value = warehouse,
        LinkedCommand = invSummarySchema.Selection.Warehouse
        },
        //Get the necessary data
        invSummarySchema.InventorySummary.InventoryID,
        invSummarySchema.InventorySummary.Warehouse,
        invSummarySchema.InventorySummary.OnHand,
        invSummarySchema.InventorySummary.Available,
        invSummarySchema.InventorySummary.AvailableForShipment
        };
        //Filter the records with non-zero quantities at the MAIN warehouse
        var filters = new Filter[]
        {
        new Filter //Adicional Filter to "FILTER FIELDS"
        {
        Field = invSummarySchema.InventorySummary.OnHand,
        Condition = FilterCondition.NotEqual,
        Value = "0",
        Operator = FilterOperator.And
        }
    };
    //Retrieve the quantities and save them to a CSV file
    String[][] items =
    context.IN401000Export(commands, filters, 0, true, false);
    IOHelper.SaveToCSVFile(items,
    string.Format(@"StockItem_Qty_InventoryID_{0}.csv", inventoryID));
}
```